# OpenCV better detection of red color?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, colors

I have the following image:

[image]

I would like to detect the red rectangle using `cv::inRange` method and HSV color space.

```
int H_MIN = 0;
int H_MAX = 10;
int S_MIN = 70; 
int S_MAX = 255;
int V_MIN = 50;
int V_MAX = 255;

cv::cvtColor( input, imageHSV, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV );

cv::inRange( imageHSV, cv::Scalar( H_MIN, S_MIN, V_MIN ), cv::Scalar( H_MAX, S_MAX, V_MAX ), imgThreshold0 );
```

I already created dynamic trackbars in order to change the values for HSV, but I can't get the desired result.

Any suggestion for best values (and maybe filters) to use?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In HSV space, the red color *wraps* around 180. So you need the `H` values to be both in [0,10] and [170, 180].

Try this:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b bgr = imread("path_to_image");

    Mat3b hsv;
    cvtColor(bgr, hsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    Mat1b mask1, mask2;
    inRange(hsv, Scalar(0, 70, 50), Scalar(10, 255, 255), mask1);
    inRange(hsv, Scalar(170, 70, 50), Scalar(180, 255, 255), mask2);

    Mat1b mask = mask1 | mask2;

    imshow("Mask", mask);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Your previous result:

[image]

Result adding range [170, 180]:

[image]

---

Another interesting approach which needs to check a single range only is:

- invert the BGR image
- convert to HSV
- look for *cyan* color

This idea has been proposed by [fmw42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43926013/5008845) and kindly pointed out by [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522989/opencv-better-detection-of-red-color/32523532?noredirect=1#comment74897695_32523532). Thank you very much for that.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b bgr = imread("path_to_image");

    Mat3b bgr_inv = ~bgr;
    Mat3b hsv_inv;
    cvtColor(bgr_inv, hsv_inv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    Mat1b mask; 
    inRange(hsv_inv, Scalar(90 - 10, 70, 50), Scalar(90 + 10, 255, 255), mask); // Cyan is 90

    imshow("Mask", mask);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a cool little trick from @fmw42 that I wanted to share... you can invert the image and look for cyans which don't wrap :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43926013/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell that's clever! Added to the answer with C++ code for completeness. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your response was super helpful! Thanks @Miki!

Comment: Can you help me please? my imshow("Mask", mask) gives an error. `error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow`. As far as I understood, the error is because mask.data == null .  What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

While working with dominant colors such as red, blue, green and yellow; analyzing the  two color channels of the [LAB color space](https://www.xrite.com/blog/lab-color-space) keeps things simple. All you need to do is apply a suitable threshold on either of the two color channels.

### 1. Detecting Red color

##### Background :

The LAB color space represents:

- the brightness value in the image in the primary channel (**L-channel**)

while colors are expressed in the two remaining channels:

- the color variations between red and green are expressed in the secondary channel (**A-channel**)
- the color variations between yellow and blue are expressed in the third channel (**B-channel**)

##### Code :

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('red.png')

# convert to LAB color space
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

# Perform Otsu threshold on the A-channel 
th = cv2.threshold(lab[:,:,1], 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

##### Result:

I have placed the LAB converted image and the threshold image besides each other.

[image]

### 2. Detecting Blue color

Now lets see how to detect blue color

Sample image:

[image]

Since I am working with blue color:

- Analyze the B-channel (since it expresses blue color better)
- Perform inverse threshold to make the blue region appear white

(***Note:*** the code changes below compared to the one above)

##### Code :

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('blue.jpg')

# convert to LAB color space
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

# Perform Otsu threshold on the A-channel 
th = cv2.threshold(lab[:,:,2], 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

##### Result:

Again, stacking the LAB and final image:

[image]

### Conclusion :

- Similar processing can be performed on green and yellow colors
- Moreover segmenting a range of one of these dominant colors is also much simpler.