# Object detection by color in openCV

Tags: opencv, colors, object-detection

I have a simple colorful image taken by camera, and I need to detect some **'Red'** circles inside of it **very accurate**.Circles have different radius and they should be distinguishable. There are some black circles in the photo also. 
Here is the procedure I followed:
1 - Convert from RGB to HSV
2 - Determining "red" upper and lower band:

```
lower_red = np.array([100, 50, 50])
upper_red = np.array([179, 255, 255])
```

3 - Create a mask. 
4 - Applying cv2.GaussianBlur to smoothing the mask and noise reduction.
5 - Detecting remaining circles by using 'cv2.HoughCircles' on **'Mask'** functions with different radius. (I have radius range)

Problem: When I create mask, the quality is not good enough, therefore Circles are detected **wrong** according to their radius.
Attachments include main photo, mask, and detected circles. 
Anybody can help to set all pixels to black appart red pixels. Or in the other words, creating a high quality mask. 
[image: Detedcted wrong circles]

[image: Blured Mask]

Comment: You need also the other red interval, with H in [0, 10]. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522989/opencv-better-detection-of-red-color/32523532#32523532)

Comment: Perfect Miki . Perfect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV better detection of red color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522989/opencv-better-detection-of-red-color)