# How to threshold the red value of an image using opencv and python

Tags: python, image, opencv, threshold

I want to identify the red value of an image. but i cannot identify the red dot.the program only shows the blue value ?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img=cv2.imread("C:\Users\My Kindom\Documents\Youcam\mihira.JPG")
hsv=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_red=np.array([100,50,50])
upper_red=np.array([130,255,255])
mask=cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_red,upper_red)
cv2.imshow("image",mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/32523532/5008845

Comment: have a look at hue range of color red. It's around 0 and 360 so for OpenCV (not sure about python openCV) it is scaled to around 0 and 180. You are looking at values between 100 and 130 (=200-260 scaled) which is part of blue: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV-Farbraum#/media/File:HueScale.svg

Comment: Thank you...you solved my problem