# get value of hue in openCV for color recognition

Tags: c++, opencv, rgb, hsv

I convert an rgb image to hsv

I used the function inRange() to detect the red color in the image

Now I want to recognize color instead of detection:
- I want to compare the hue value against the range of red color .. if it lies within it .. print red
else if it lies in blue range say blue .. so on

How to compare Mat hue if it is in the range 100 to 180??

```
int main()
{

Mat image;
image = imread("C:/Users/Maram/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/firsttrialw310/x64/Debug/carcolor.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

if (!image.data)
{
    cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

// Create a new matrix to hold the HSV image
Mat HSV;

// convert RGB image to HSV
cvtColor(image, HSV, CV_RGB2HSV);

namedWindow("Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Display window", image);

namedWindow("Result window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Result window", HSV);


vector<Mat> hsv_planes;
split(HSV, hsv_planes);
Mat h = hsv_planes[0]; // H channel
Mat s = hsv_planes[1]; // S channel
Mat v = hsv_planes[2]; // V channel

namedWindow("hue", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("hue", h);
namedWindow("saturation", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("saturation", s);
namedWindow("value", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("value", v);



//// red color range
Scalar hsv_l(100, 150, 150);
Scalar hsv_h(180, 255, 255);
Mat bw;
inRange(HSV, hsv_l, hsv_h, bw);
imshow("Specific Colour", bw);
////

//black cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(180, 255, 40, 0)
//white cv::Scalar(0, 0, 80, 0), cv::Scalar(180, 255, 255, 0)




waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post an example image.What happens if an image has both red and blue? Also take care that you aren't setting the red range [correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32523532/5008845)

Comment: call cv::Vec3b hsvVal = hsv.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x); int hVal = hsvVal[0];

Comment: @Micka can u explain more or write your code to compare within ranges in an answer?

Comment: did my answer in previous question help you?

Comment: yes in the detection part

Comment: @Miki the image will have 1 color only