# OpenCV inRange() function

Tags: c++, opencv, color-detection

I try to run the following code:

```
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>

using namespace cv;


int main() {

    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);


    while (1) {

Mat src;
Mat threshold;

cap.read(src);

inRange(src, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(255, 0, 0), threshold);
imshow("thr", threshold);
imshow("hsv", src);

        waitKey(33);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it seems like it doesn't filter because there is only a blank window appearing when I run the code.

How to get that code to detect red colors?

Comment: can you see your source image properly? or a black window?

Comment: Thank you for replying, I see the source image properly.

Comment: you forgot to convert to hsv the `src` image ;D Also, in OpenCV uses BGR, not RGB, so you are thresholding the blue channel. So, in BGR your thresholds should be something like: `inRange(src, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(50, 50, 255), threshold);` Better use HSV color space, see the duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV better detection of red color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522989/opencv-better-detection-of-red-color)

Comment: Thank you for replying, I tried using the suggestion in the liked you supplied, but, it also filters and shows many other captured objects which are originally not red, is there any way to make the filtering more accurate? btw, why can't I use: inRange(src, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(0, 0, 255), threshold);?

Comment: @Miki opencv c++ Scalar are in HSV or in BGR format?

Comment: @user scalars are just numbers

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify `inRange` function like this:

```
inRange(src, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(255, 255, 255), threshold);
```

If you try to threshold just the first channel (the blue channel), then you have to make other channels free, so set it to `0` in `lawerb` and its `dtype`, usually `255` for `np.uint8`

E.g.

```
inRange(src, Scalar(0, 50, 0), Scalar(255, 100, 255), threshold);
```

this line will compare the 2nd channel (the green channel) and ignore others.