# Calculation of percentage of filled-in color in particular ROI?

Tags: opencv, colors, percentage

here is an example. I have a health bar. If player has 100% HP, he has his health bar all the way red. If he gets attacked, part of the health bar is red and the rest is dark (as he lost some HP). I made a ROI on the place where his health bar is. How would I calculate a percentage of his life using OpenCV?

Comment: (number of red pixels / roi area) * 100 ?

Comment: Thanks for input, but how do I get only red pixels? I know I can calculate all the pixels using mat.total(), but dont know how to do it only for red pixels? Should I use some treshold?

Comment: Yes, you can use `inRange`, and then `countNonZero`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32523532/5008845) to see how to start

Comment: Updated main question with actual code. Getting error on countNonZero :/

Comment: `int ZeroPixels = TotalPixels - countNonZero(mask);`

Comment: Thanks, that helped. However, when I try : 
    float ProcentualLife = ((countNonZero(mask) / 1705) * 100);

it does not update my procentual life. Its always 0, not matter what the number of pixels is. I dont understand it. 1705 is number of all pixels in roi.

Comment: Solved it! The problem was in integer truncation. Solved it using float instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final solution I got. Thanks to Miki

```
Mat testBar = src(Rec_UserBarHP);
Mat testBarHSV;

cvtColor(testBar, testBarHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

Mat mask1;
inRange(testBarHSV, Scalar(0, 70, 50), Scalar(10, 255, 255), mask1);
Mat mask = mask1;

int TotalPixels = testBarHSV.rows * testBarHSV.cols;
float ZeroPixels = TotalPixels - countNonZero(testBarHSV);

ostringstream str;
str << "Number of red pixels:" << ZeroPixels;
putText(src, str.str(),
    Point(5, 5), 
    FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 
    1.0, 
    Scalar(255, 255, 255), 
    1, 
    CV_AA);
```