# OpenCV can't detect color red correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, image-processing, colors

Recently, I'm trying to use java OpenCV to detect the color of a Rubik's Cube. My Rubik's Cube has six colors including white, yellow, orange, red, blue and green. The color space I use is HSV color space. According to Wiki, each color has their unique range of Hue value, so theoretically I can use Hue solely to determine which color I detect(except color white I use Saturation). However, this method works well for all colors except for red. The Hue value range I used for red is (179 >= hue >= 160 || 6.5 >= hue >= 0), but the actual value I got can range between almost any color. Red can be detected as all other colors except for white. What could be the reason? Is is possible that there's sth wrong in OpenCV? Below is the code I used to read color from the image. Thanks for any suggestion.

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(oriImage, hsvImg, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
Imgproc.medianBlur(hsvImg, hsvImg, 5);
double[] color = new double[3];
double[] data = new double[3];
int sqr = (size*2+1)*(size*2+1);

//up left corner sampling
for(int i = centerX-size ; i<=centerX+size ; i++)
    for(int j = centerY-size ; j<=centerY+size ; j++)
    {
        data = hsvImg.get(j, i);
        color[0] += data[0]; color[1] += data[1]; color[2] += data[2];
    }
color[0] /= sqr; //Hue
color[1] /= sqr; //Saturation
color[2] /= sqr; //Value

if(color[1] <= 65)//if saturation is smaller than 65
    return standardWhite;
else if(color[0]>=18.49 && color[0]<= 35.49)
    return standardYellow;
else if((color[0]>=160 && color[0]<= 179)||(color[0]>=0 && color[0]<=6.49))
    return standardRed;
else if(color[0]>=6.5 && color[0]<= 17)
    return standardOrange;
else if(color[0]>=35.5 && color[0]<= 92)
    return standardGreen;
else if(color[0]>=100 && color[0]<= 158)
    return standardBlue;
else//color detection failed
    return standardGray;
```

Sample Image:

[image: an example]

Comment: "Is is possible that there's sth wrong in OpenCV?" -- Sure, it's possible, but given you're only calling 2 very commonly used functions, it's highly unlikely (compared to the possibility of there being something wrong with your code or algorithm).

Comment: The root of the problem is in how you're calculating the mean HSV value of a tile -- specifically the Hue component. You see, unlike saturation and value which are linear quantities, hue is a circular quantity (similar to an angle, or time of day) -- it wraps around. Unfortunately, the arithmetic mean you calculated is not suitable for such quantity. You either need to take [a different approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities), or perhaps calculate the mean while still in RGB colour space.

Comment: To illustrate -- imagine you have two red pixels, one with hue 5, the other with hue 175. Arithmetic mean of the hues becomes (175+5)/2 = 90 (green), whereas you'd expect it to be 0. Various proportions of red pixels with "low" and "high" hue values will cause the arithmetic mean to fall anywhere in the valid range, resulting in what you describe -- red being classified as anything other than a white.

Comment: I got it!!!!!! I forgot to put it into consideration when calculating the mean. Thank you so much!!! I will try it later.

Comment: You can use the LAB color space to better segment red color see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522989/opencv-better-detection-of-red-color/72155970#72155970