# how to create LAB color chart using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, graph

I am developing a project that has as a starting point to identify the colors of certain spots, for this I am plotting 3D graphics with the RGB colors of these images. With this I have identified some striking colors of these spots, as seen below.

[image]

Color is a matter of perception and subjectivity of interpretation. The purpose of this step is to identify so that you can find a pattern of color without differences of interpretation. With this, I have been searching the internet and for this, it is recommended to use the [color space L * a * b *](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space).

With this, can someone help me to obtain this graph with the colors LAB, or indicate another way to better classify the colors of these spots?

Code used to plot 3d graph

```
import numpy as np
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import colorsys
from PIL import Image

# (1) Import the file to be analyzed!
img_file = Image.open("IMD405.png")
img = img_file.load()

# (2) Get image width & height in pixels
[xs, ys] = img_file.size
max_intensity = 100
hues = {}

# (3) Examine each pixel in the image file
for x in xrange(0, xs):
  for y in xrange(0, ys):
    # (4)  Get the RGB color of the pixel
    [r, g, b] = img[x, y]

# (5)  Normalize pixel color values
r /= 255.0
g /= 255.0
b /= 255.0

# (6)  Convert RGB color to HSV
[h, s, v] = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b)

# (7)  Marginalize s; count how many pixels have matching (h, v)
if h not in hues:
  hues[h] = {}
if v not in hues[h]:
  hues[h][v] = 1
else:
  if hues[h][v] < max_intensity:
    hues[h][v] += 1

# (8)   Decompose the hues object into a set of one dimensional arrays we can use with matplotlib
h_ = []
v_ = []
i = []
colours = []

for h in hues:
  for v in hues[h]:
    h_.append(h)
    v_.append(v)
    i.append(hues[h][v])
    [r, g, b] = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h, 1, v)
    colours.append([r, g, b])

# (9)   Plot the graph!
fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(h_, v_, i, s=5, c=colours, lw=0)

ax.set_xlabel('Hue')
ax.set_ylabel('Value')
ax.set_zlabel('Intensity')
fig.add_axes(ax)
plt.savefig('plot-IMD405.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I would suggest you use RGB for this. HSV (or similar, as in your plot) are systems that make it easy to choose a color, don't use them for quantification. CIE Lab and CIE Luv are designed for quantification of color *perception*. They try to model the human color perception. There are good arguments as to why many tasks should be independent of perception. RGB simply divides the spectrum (roughly) into 3 bands, quantifying in RGB tells you something about the properties of the light reflected/absorbed by the object under study.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ok, I get it. But the proposal is rightly placed in LAB because it is the color space closest to the human view and compare the colors that the algorithm identified with the colors that the dermatologist rated

Comment: Oh, so this is a mole? Wouldn't have recognized it! :) -- Yes, if you want to imitate human perception, go with Lab. If you want to improve over the dermatologist, go with RGB. And add infrared too, which penetrates the skin a bit and can give you a very different view of the mole than what visible light gives. You can then measure stuff that the dermatologist cannot see, so you can really provide additional data for diagnosis.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, you know how I can extract the colors in LAB space Do you have pictures plotting in the graphic? I search the internet but I do not think anything like it

Comment: You're using `rgb_to_hsv`, is there no `rgb_to_lab`? I haven't used OpenCV much, so I don't konw, but that is where I would start looking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using OpenCV for Python is really straightforward. Here I created a function to plot a sample image. Note that for this function the image must be RGB or BGR.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

image_BGR = np.uint8(np.random.rand(50,50,3) * 255)
#this image above is just an example. To load a real image use the line below
#image_BGR = cv2.imread('path/to/image')

def toLAB(image, input_type = 'BGR'):
  conversion = cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB if input_type == 'BGR' else cv2.COLOR_RGB2LAB
  image_LAB = cv2.cvtColor(image, conversion)

  y,x,z = image_LAB.shape
  LAB_flat = np.reshape(image_LAB, [y*x,z])

  colors = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) if input_type == 'BGR' else image
  colors = np.reshape(colors, [y*x,z])/255.

  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
  ax.scatter(xs=LAB_flat[:,2], ys=LAB_flat[:,1], zs=LAB_flat[:,0], s=10,  c=colors, lw=0)
  ax.set_xlabel('A')
  ax.set_ylabel('B')
  ax.set_zlabel('L')

  plt.show()

  return image_LAB 

lab_image = toLAB(image_BGR)
```

The result is something like this:

[image: LBA scatter plot]

I hope it helped!

Comment: @TecnologiadaNet I jus added a comment with the line to read the image from file, just uncomment that, comment the other one and set the right path.

Comment: Guilherme, I've circled the code, both the first and the one with an input image, and there is no output or error msg.

Comment: Ok, I dited the function so it will now plot the scatter if you are not running on a notebook. Also, I added a return: now the function returns the converted image

Comment: I have added the plt.show (), but even so, it does not appear if you want the graph plotted, the code is running right there?

Comment: i see, I guess you were not calling the function. So now i added: `lab_image = toLAB(image_BGR)`

Comment: now it's turned, thank you. Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840610/how-to-discard-the-edges-of-an-image-using-opencv?noredirect=1#comment92598069_52840610

Answer (score 0):

> The static map:

[image]
[image]

> The gif map:

[image]
[image]

I prefer to use HSV to look up for specific color range, such as:

> 1. [Choosing the correct upper and lower HSV boundaries for color detection with`cv::inRange` (OpenCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv/48367205#48367205)
> 2. [How to define a threshold value to detect only green colour objects in an image :Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483951/how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image/47483966#47483966)
> 3. [How to detect two different colors using `cv2.inRange` in Python-OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109650/how-to-detect-two-different-colors-using-cv2-inrange-in-python-opencv/48117624?s=37|15.8985#48117624)
> 4. [what are recommended color spaces for detecting orange color in open cv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48528754/what-are-recommended-color-spaces-for-detecting-orange-color-in-open-cv/48533523?s=2|41.2386#48533523)

Comment: right, but I need to do using the Lab space, because it is the closest to human vision, and to be able to compare the results according to the human classification

Answer (score 0):

```
# load the input image 
image = cv2.imread(image_file)

# Change to RGB space
image_RGB = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

#plt.imshow(image_RGB)
#plt.show()

# get pixel color
pixel_colors = image_RGB.reshape((np.shape(image_RGB)0]*np.shape(image_RGB)[1], 3))

norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=-1.,vmax=1.)

norm.autoscale(pixel_colors)

pixel_colors = norm(pixel_colors).tolist()

# Change to lab space
image_LAB = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB )


(L_chanel, A_chanel, B_chanel) = cv2.split(image_LAB)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.0, 6.0))

axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection="3d")

axis.scatter(L_chanel.flatten(), A_chanel.flatten(), B_chanel.flatten(), facecolors = pixel_colors, marker = ".")
axis.set_xlabel("L:ightness")
axis.set_ylabel("A:red/green coordinate")
axis.set_zlabel("B:yellow/blue coordinate")

plt.show()
```