# Detect both red and blue color objects simultaneously and apply mask

Tags: python, opencv, colors, raspberry-pi

I am doing a project which detects helmets using raspberry pi camera.So I have blue and red color helmets.Now I need to detect both the colors and apply mask. But I know how to detect only one color at a time.

Comment: Please be more specific and post the code what you have tried with.

Comment: it would be useful if you could add your input image and the code you have for detecting a single colour.

Comment: Use `cv2.inRange()` twice and **or** the results together.

Comment: See here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/48117624/2836621

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the color detector 2 times with the differents colors ranges. Don't forget that use the image returned from the first detection on the second.

I have an example [here](https://github.com/marcosvpinho/PI3/blob/master/Testes/color_figure_detector.py)