# Py script for fishing minigame cv2.matchTemplate

Tags: python, opencv, template-matching

I am trying to make a script for fishing minigame, there is a post with a fishing script for albion online, the problem is that in this game the pointer is very thin and there are many different textures and colors, to the simple grayscale matching works good on one part of the slider (for example on the water texture), sometimes work on others(trees texture) and does not work on the third (ex. sky). If I change to lower threshold it activates often without matching.

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQbcF.png)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from mss.windows import MSS as mss
from PIL import Image
import time
import pyautogui as pg
import cv2
import mss
import numpy

template = cv2.imread("perfect3.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(
    history=10,
    varThreshold=2,
    detectShadows=False)

with mss.mss() as sct:
    monitor = {"top": 344, "left": 4419, "width": 150, "height": 666}

    while "Screen capturing":
        last_time = time.time()
        img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))
        gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray_frame, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        loc = np.where(res >= 0.85)
        for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
            cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
            print('click')
        cv2.imshow("OpenCV/Numpy normal", img)

        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Tried it also with edge detection cv2.canny without luck.

The point is to click the button when the fish is in the smallest green field. The field appears in random parts of a slider.

Any ideas?

================

## UPDATE

Tried color matching as Furas said

```
# import the necessary packages
from collections import deque
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import imutils
import time
from mss.linux import MSS as mss
from PIL import Image
import mss
import numpy
import pyautogui
# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",
    help="path to the (optional) video file")
ap.add_argument("-b", "--buffer", type=int, default=64,
    help="max buffer size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# define the lower and upper boundaries of the "green"
# ball in the HSV color space, then initialize the
# list of tracked points
greenLower = (42, 84, 211)
greenUpper = (69, 130, 255)
blueLower = (88, 76, 255)
blueUpper = (151, 76, 255)
pts = deque(maxlen=args["buffer"])

# grab video from screen(monitor area)
with mss.mss() as sct:
    monitor = {"top": 325, "left": 4423, "width": 136, "height": 662}
    while "Screen capturing":
        #last_time = time.time()
        #vs = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))
        #print("fps: {}".format(1 / (time.time() - last_time)))
        vs = sct.grab(monitor)
        # grab the current frame
        #frame = vs
        frame = np.array(vs)
        # resize the frame, blur it, and convert it to the HSV
        # color space
        blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        # construct a mask for the color "green", then perform
        # a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small
        # blobs left in the mask
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, greenLower, greenUpper)
        mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
        mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)
        mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, blueLower, blueUpper)
        mask2 = cv2.erode(mask2, None, iterations=2)
        mask2 = cv2.dilate(mask2, None, iterations=2)
        # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
        # (x, y) center of the ball
        cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
        center = None
        cnts2 = cv2.findContours(mask2.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts2 = imutils.grab_contours(cnts2)
        center2 = None
        # only proceed if at least one contour was found
        if len(cnts) > 0:
            # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
            # it to compute the minimum enclosing rectangle and
            # centroid
            c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            M = cv2.moments(c)
            center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
            c2 = max(cnts2, key=cv2.contourArea)
            (x2, y2, w2, h2) = cv2.boundingRect(c2)
            M2 = cv2.moments(c2)
            center2 = (int(M2["m10"] / M2["m00"]), int(M2["m01"] / M2["m00"]))
            # draw the rectangle and centroid on the frame,
            # then update the list of tracked points
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), (int(x+w), int(y+h)),(0, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (int(x2), int(y2)), (int(x2+w2), int(y2+h2)),(0, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(frame, center2, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
            # update the points queue
            pts.appendleft(center)
            if y-15 < y2 < y+15:
                pyautogui.click(4908, 984)
                time.sleep(2)
                y2 = 0           
        cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

But before the round or between rounds i get error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Game\Desktop\Py\Fish.py", line 74, in <module>
    c2 = max(cnts2, key=cv2.contourArea)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

How can it be solved?

Going to change the two masks in one as Furas adviced

```
mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask1, mask2)
```

But what can i use to find both max for green field and fish?
till now it was 2 masks, 2 cnts and 2 max values.

With mss sct.grab i have not so great FPS (average 25fps) any other better capturing methods?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you try to match thin line or fish attached to this line ?

Comment: did you try to search point with color which is used in fish ? The same with small green field.

Comment: I tried both fish and thin line. You mean search coordinates of both fish and green field by colour? That i havn't tried yet.

Comment: `fish` has only one color so I was thining about replacing other colors with black - `image[ np.all(image != (179,254,255), axis=2) ] = [0,0,0]` - it should reduce number of elements on image. But maybe `inRange()` would be more useful. [How to detect two different colors using `cv2.inRange` in Python-OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109650/how-to-detect-two-different-colors-using-cv2-inrange-in-python-opencv). But I didn't try to use it to get position of this `fish`.

Comment: Tried it with color matching with `inRange()` , it works, but i have faced other problems in my script. Updated the question.

Comment: you check `len(cnts) > 0:` but it seems you have to also check `len(cnts2) > 0:` because your current error means `cnts2` is empty.

Comment: or maybe you should join `cnts` and `cnts2` - it both are lists then `cnts + cnts2` should join lists.

Comment: Will try tomorrow, but how can i find both max with one cnts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some workaround i got it working and tested, with a colour detection it works on the firs "day map". Not always get "perfect" hit, but at least "good", guess it is becouse of FPS procession, maybee if I find the way to reise FPS, than it would be better.

```
    # import the necessary packages
from collections import deque
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import imutils
import time
from mss.linux import MSS as mss
from PIL import Image
import mss
import pyautogui
from win32 import win32gui
from pythonwin import win32ui
from win32.lib import win32con
from win32 import win32api

# define the lower and upper boundaries in the HSV color space, then initialize the
# list of tracked points
# Green "perfect" field
greenLower = (42, 79, 211)
greenUpper = (69, 130, 255)
# Blue fish
blueLower = (88, 76, 255)
blueUpper = (151, 76, 255)
# Purple field
blue2Lower = (114, 139, 218)
blue2Upper = (123, 165, 255)
# Gray field "Status" (after fish is caught)
grayLower = (0, 0, 114)
grayUpper = (0, 0, 132)
# Purple miss
purpleLower = (123, 148, 239)
purpleUpper = (125, 165, 243)
# Define Vars
y2 = 0
a = 0
b = 0
startTime = time.time()
startTime2 = time.time()
# grab video from screen(monitor area)
with mss.mss() as sct:
    #grab picture of slider and fish
    monitor = {"top": 846, "left": 4726, "width": 162, "height": 398}
    #grab picture of gray field "Status" when the fish is caught
    monitor2 = {"top": 1017, "left": 4366, "width": 11, "height": 23}
    #grab picture of purple pixels if fish is lost
    monitor3 = {"top": 1013, "left": 4484, "width": 5, "height": 6}
    while "Screen capturing":
        vs = sct.grab(monitor)
        vs2 = sct.grab(monitor2)
        vs3 = sct.grab(monitor3) 
        # grab the current frame
        frame = np.array(vs)
        frame2 = np.array(vs2)
        frame3 = np.array(vs3)
        # resize the frame, blur it, and convert it to the HSV
        # color space
        blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        blurred2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame2, (11, 11), 0)
        hsv2 = cv2.cvtColor(blurred2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        blurred3 = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame3, (11, 11), 0)
        hsv3 = cv2.cvtColor(blurred3, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        # construct a mask for the color, then perform
        # a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small
        # blobs left in the mask
        # Mask for green 'perfect' field
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, greenLower, greenUpper)
        mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
        mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)
        # Mask for Fish
        mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, blueLower, blueUpper)
        mask2 = cv2.erode(mask2, None, iterations=2)
        mask2 = cv2.dilate(mask2, None, iterations=2)
        # Mask for purple Start slider
        mask3 = cv2.inRange(hsv, blue2Lower, blue2Upper)
        mask3 = cv2.erode(mask3, None, iterations=2)
        mask3 = cv2.dilate(mask3, None, iterations=2)
        # Mask for gray field "Status" when the fish is caught
        mask4 = cv2.inRange(hsv2, grayLower, grayUpper)
        mask4 = cv2.erode(mask4, None, iterations=2)
        mask4 = cv2.dilate(mask4, None, iterations=2)
        # Mask for purple fish miss
        mask5 = cv2.inRange(hsv3, purpleLower, purpleUpper)
        mask5 = cv2.erode(mask5, None, iterations=2)
        mask5 = cv2.dilate(mask5, None, iterations=2)
        # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
        # (x, y) center of the rectangle
        cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
        cnts2 = cv2.findContours(mask2.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts2 = imutils.grab_contours(cnts2)
        cnts3 = cv2.findContours(mask3.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts3 = imutils.grab_contours(cnts3)
        cnts4 = cv2.findContours(mask4.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts4 = imutils.grab_contours(cnts4)
        cnts5 = cv2.findContours(mask5.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts5 = imutils.grab_contours(cnts5)
        # only proceed if at least one contour was found
        if len(cnts3) > 0:
            print ("start")
            startTime2 = time.time()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            pyautogui.click(4978, 1239)
            time.sleep(1)
            startTime2 = time.time()
        elif len(cnts) > 0 and len(cnts2) > 0:
            startTime2 = time.time()
            # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
            # it to compute the minimum enclosing rectangle and
            # centroid
            c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
            M = cv2.moments(c)
            center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
            (x, y) = center
            c2 = max(cnts2, key=cv2.contourArea)
            M2 = cv2.moments(c2)
            center2 = (int(M2["m10"] / M2["m00"]), int(M2["m01"] / M2["m00"]))
            (x2, y2) = center2
            if y-65 < y2 < y+65:
                print ("catch")
                pyautogui.click(4978, 1239)
                time.sleep(1)
                y2 = 0
                startTime2 = time.time()
        elif len(cnts4) > 0:
            time.sleep(1)
            a +=1
            endTime = time.time()
            timer = endTime-startTime
            hour = timer // 3600
            timer %= 3600
            minutes = timer // 60
            timer %= 60
            seconds = timer
            print (a, "fishes and", b, "misses in %d:%d:%d" % (hour, minutes, seconds))
            print ("start over")
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.click(4741, 913)
            pyautogui.click(4741, 913)
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.click(4978, 1239)
            pyautogui.click(4978, 1239)
            time.sleep(1)
            startTime2 = time.time()
        elif len(cnts5) > 0:
            b +=1
            print ("Miss")
            time.sleep(2)
            pyautogui.click(4978, 1239)
            startTime2 = time.time()
        else:
            endTime2 = time.time()
            if (endTime2 - startTime2 > 40):
                print("Longer than 40 seconds")
                startTime2 = time.time()
                print ("restart")
                pyautogui.click(4741, 913)
                time.sleep(1)
                pyautogui.click(4978, 1239)
                time.sleep(1) 
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```