# How to detect filled line in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, contour

I've used Canny and findContour to detect my contours of drawn coloured lines.
However, because of this, I am currently facing a problem of having lines being bounded.
What I want is to overlay and detect the entire line.

This is what I have now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8i3s.jpg

I want the blue detection lines to cover the entire line that is being drawn. Not just the perimeter of the line drawn.
How is this possible?

Comment: if you want to detect the lines which are only in blue then use the Opencv inrange() method.for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109650/how-to-detect-two-different-colors-using-cv2-inrange-in-python-opencv

Comment: No, what's shown in the image is a red and black maze respectively, with drawContour() in blue. The contour drawn (in blue) only covers the perimeter of the pen-drawn lines. I want the entire pen-drawn lines to be in blue.

Answer (score 0):

The perimeter of pen-drawn line is highlighted with blue because you are using 1 as thickness in `drawContours()` function. To fill it with blue, set `thickness = -1` in `drawContours()`.

[Refer this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#how-to-draw-the-contours)