# are there any other syntaxe can make it work?

Tags: python, numpy

```
 if image[i][j][1]>=lower_red and image[i][j][1]<=upper_red:
```

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: can you print what `image[i][j][1]` returns and post it? also, what are the values of `lower_red` and `upper_red`?

Comment: Use a.any() or a.all() perhaps?

Comment: Since you are using OpenCV, you should use `cv2.inRange` instead. [See example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109650/how-to-detect-two-different-colors-using-cv2-inrange-in-python-opencv)

Comment: If you still need help then please print out `image.shape`, `lower_red.shape` and `upper_red.shape` and share the results with us!

Comment: the error is in the condition it self / i have tried .all() and .any() but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is the right answer:

```py
if ((image[i][j][1] >= lower_red).all()) and ((image[i][j][1] <= upper_red).any()):
    ...
```

Comment: Are you looping through each pixel in the image? If so, this is not optimal

Answer (score -1):

This does work when called in the correct way...

- I make a suitable image array (list of lists) that has 3 dimensions.
- I set values for upper an lower for testing.
- I then add the logical check with an `if-else`.

This works:

```py
# example image 3d array
image = [
    [[5,6,5],[1,2,3]],
    [[1,2,3],[5,6,5]]
    ]

# some values to check
lower_red = 10
upper_red = 10

# example of checking
i, j = 0,1
if image[i][j][1]>=lower_red and image[i][j][1]<=upper_red:
    print('done')
else:
    print(image[i][j][1])
```

result:

```
2
```