# whats the ranges of the red in HSV?

Tags: image-processing, hsv

i want to detect red objects in an image.so i convert RGB img to HSV. so in order to know the range of red color i used color pallet on this site 
https://alloyui.com/examples/color-picker/hsv
I found out that H(Hue) is falling between 0 to 10 as a lower limit and 340 to 359 as an upper limit. also i found out that the maximum value of S(Saturation) and V(value) is 100. but the problem is that i found some people say the ranges  of red H: 0 to 10 as lower limit and 160 to 180 as uper limit.
https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/05/08/detect-red-circles-image-using-opencv/
[OpenCV better detection of red color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522989/opencv-better-detection-of-red-color)
 also they said the maximum S and V is 255.[This is color i got when i tried to find the upper limit of the red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWsEo.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different definitions of HSV, so the values your particular conversion function gives are the ones your should use. Measuring them is the best way to know for sure.

In principle H is an angle, so it goes from 0 to 360, with red centered around 0 (and understanding that 360==0). But some implementations will divide that by 2 to fit it in 8 bits. Others scale to a full 0-255 rage for the 8 bits.

The same is true for S and V. Sometimes they're values between 0 and 100, sometimes they go up to 255.

To measure, create an image where you have pure red pixels (RGB value 255,0,0), and convert. That will give your the center of red hue (H) and the max saturation (S). Then make an image that changes from orange to purple, these colors are near red. You should then see the range of H. Finally, make a pure white image (255,255,255). This will have maximum intensity (V).