# Having trouble with imread() method of OpenCV - Mat mask.data always return null (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, opencv

I am developing an App that detects red little rectangles from an image.
I have a code (gotten from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522989/opencv-better-detection-of-red-color) answer here) that apparently does that.

The code states that I need to use the `imread()` method with the String file name as a parameter.

The steps: I open the camera. I take a picture, display it on screen and save it to the App's file directory. Then, using the code mentioned, I use the `imread()` to reference the image and get the job done.

I don't know if I am doing something wrong or what, but `mask.data` `ALWAYS returns NULL`. I believe that the problem lies on the `imread()` file path given wrong, thus `Mat3b brg` is empty, and then the error is created.

Can someone enlighten me on that?

Below is the code I got so far:

```
//The snippet begins after the picture is taken

//First Part of Method - closing the camera and adding the result view
[photoCam stop];

resultView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageView.bounds];
UIImage* result = image;
[resultView setImage:result];
resultView.center = imageView.center;
[self.view addSubview:resultView];

//Second Part of the Method - saving the image to a file
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(result) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

//Third Part of the Method - reading the red rectangles
Mat3b bgr = cv::imread("image.png"); // Here is where I believe the problem is. HELP!!!!
//Already tried the absolute path of the image, like 
// "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BAB824A7-C7C1-4D1E-BB4A-43A003F30F1A/Documents/image.png"
// Didn't work either.

Mat3b hsv;
cvtColor(bgr, hsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

Mat1b mask1, mask2;
inRange(hsv, Scalar(0, 70, 50), Scalar(10, 255, 255), mask1);
inRange(hsv, Scalar(170, 70, 50), Scalar(180, 255, 255), mask2);

Mat1b mask = mask1 | mask2;

if (mask.data == NULL)
{
    NSLog(@"mask.data == null");
}
else
{
    namedWindow("Mask", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Mask", mask);
    waitKey();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use the absolute path to the image. Probably your working directory is not where you expect it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried it, but the error is the same.
I got the path printing on log the `filePath` var.

Comment: does your application have permissions to access the file/directory? Can you try to write a file, like "test.txt"?

Comment: have a look at: https://answers.opencv.org/question/13360/imread-in-ios/

Comment: Hey! Your tip did the trick. Now I get value on `mask.data`. I am getting another error though. But for the matter of this question, you helped me solve it. Post your comment as an answer so I can accept and upvote it!
FYI, I will post the error I am getting now, in comment below:

Comment: `OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file /Volumes/build-storage/build/master_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 593
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Volumes/build-storage/build/master_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:593: error: (-2)`

It says something about Linux, and Windows, but I am using Mac OS.

Comment: your system doesnt allow you ro create a namedWindow and imshow. Not sure about how to solve that in iOs. Maybe you can use native functions to show images?

Comment: please write the answer yourself, I'll upvote the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting help from `Micka`, I found the solution for the problem.

I was trying to read the image using the `imread()` method, which was not finding the file path (no matter what path I used), hence not returning anything, so in the end `mask.data` was returning NULL.

`Micka` suggested me to read [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/13360/imread-in-ios/) tread posted on OpenCV's official forum.
In the first answer there, someone suggested that the image is passed as a parameter using UIImage, rather than using the path of the file.
So, this is what I did, and voilá, `mask.data` is returning the value of the image.

Here is the code which did the trick:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(result) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

UIImage* resImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
cv::Mat3b bgr;
UIImageToMat(resImage, bgr);

Mat3b hsv;
cvtColor(bgr, hsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
```

Thanks `Micka`!